# Skipping Characters in C

Tags: c, replace, split, special-characters, strtok

```c
    char string[10] = "1    2 3, \n4, 5\n 2; 3 is fun 1 2! 3";
    char *token = strtok(string, " ");
    for (int i =0; i < sizeof(string) / sizeof(char) ; i++){
        if (isspace(string[i]) == 0 || string[i] != "." || string[i] != ";" || string[i] != "," || string[i] != "!") {
            printf("word %c\n", string[i]);
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure what I am trying to do is a bit obvious, but how do I do it?
What I am actually trying to do is to use strtok(string, "any white space or, !; etc..")
Then I was searching for how to ignore these characters generally in a string.

my problem is that it takes \n4 as one character I believe even in the case of 3, it would take 3, as one character

```c
    char *token = strtok(string, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        words[count] = token;
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

This is the thing I am actually trying to implement, but here it only removes spaces.

Comment: The code is incomplete and it is not clear what "*it takes \n4 as one character I believe even in the case of 3*" means. Please provide a [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. I

Comment: `string` array size is not large enough to hold the characters of string used to initialise it. Omit the size and let the compiler compute it for you, like this - `char string[] = "1    2 3, \n4, 5\n 2; 3 is fun 1 2! 3";`

Comment: Using `||` and `!=` is going to match EVERYTHING because if it's not one thing it's another...

Comment: If you trying to implement tokens that are separated by a space *or* a newline *or* an exclamation point, you don't need anything other than `strtok(..., " \n!")`.

Comment: Why not use `strtok(NULL, ".;,! \r\n\t");`? You already know that function exists. This is truly just a matter of reading the `strtok` documentation. That is what most of us do when we are in doubt.

Comment: @Cheatah Oh, I didn't know that I could add multiple delimiter conditions. Thought it was going to take them as one type of delemiter.
I will try that out thanks!

Comment: @kaylum for the second portion of the code, assume the string is the same array in the first snippet. Of course, there's no main function in my snippet, just to minimize the size of the question didn't add it. As it's a must to have part of the code anyway.

Comment: @H.S. Thanks for the notice, didn't know that we can have flexibility in choosing the array size :).

Comment: @Fe2O3 could you elaborate please?

Comment: A 'full stop' is not a 'semicolon', and a 'semicolon' is not a 'full stop'... So, both 'semicolons 'and 'full stops' will find a condition that let's them be printed. Same applies to any other character you choose. (Perhaps my comment should have been "If it's one thing, then it's not another...") You gotta think about boolean logic.

Comment: @ProfessorSeemo Be careful while using `strtok()` because it modify the string passed to it if that string contains any (separator) characters which is part of string passed as delimiter to `strtok()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't write this:

```
char *token = strtok(string, " ");
    while(token != NULL) {
        words[count] = token;
        count++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

The function designer made it SO VERY EASY

```
for( char *tkn = string; ( tkn = strtok( tkn, " " ) ) != NULL; tkn = NULL )
    /* do stuff with tkn */
```

ONE invocation of the function, ONE instance of the separator string.

---

If you want a non-destructive version of `strtok()` you can write your own. Here's something to work from.

```
int main() {
    char *p = "1    2 3, \n4, 5\n 2; 3 is fun 1 2! 3";

    char *rjct = " ,\n;!";

    while( *p ) {
        while( *p &&  strchr( rjct, *p ) ) p++;
        while( *p && !strchr( rjct, *p ) ) putchar( *p++ );
        printf( "-SEP-" ); // or simply putchar( ' ' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

```
1-SEP-2-SEP-3-SEP-4-SEP-5-SEP-2-SEP-3-SEP-is-SEP-fun-SEP-1-SEP-2-SEP-3-SEP-
```

---

And with a few subtle changes it converts from *exclude* to *include*

```
int main() {
    char *p = "110   27 3, \n4, 5\n 2; 3 is fun 1 2! 3";

    char *keep = "0123456789";

    while( *p ) {
        while( *p && !strchr( keep, *p ) ) p++;
        while( *p &&  strchr( keep, *p ) ) putchar( *p++ );
        putchar( ' ' );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

```
110 27 3 4 5 2 3 1 2 3
```